# Using an image as the parent Activity (interface)

Tags: android, android-image

Is it possible to use an image as the background of the main Activity? (load screen).  I then want to put buttons over the image. If this is possible could anyone tell me how I would load the image into my main Activity?  Or send me to a site that would go over this?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should probably read up more about android layouts and then ask more specific questions about the problems you face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following to set a background image for an Activity..

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) {
    view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.bground_land);
} else {
    view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.bground_port);
}
```

`bground_land.jpg` and `bground_port.jpg` are images in my project's /res/drawable directory.